# Restricting Multilanguages for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to restrict the input field from non English languages.Only English should be enter on the field.

MY textbox is

```
<input type="text"/>
```

The function is

```
 $(document).on("keypress", "input[type='text'] function (event) {
        return suppressNonEng(event);
    });

function suppressNonEng(EventKey) {
    var key = EventKey.which || EventKey.keyCode;
    if (key > 128) { sefAlert("Only English is allowed"); return false; }
    else { return true; }
}
```

Its worked in the case of Chinese,Greek and some other also.But in the case of Spanish,French, its not working because the same ASCII character is used in the English and French. Is there any solution for this problem?please help

Comment: You will have to validate this on the server side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/Fn9cy/36/)

Its pretty simple. You need to match every character entered with a regex that checks whether the character entered is from the English alphabet, or not.

```
$("#mytextbox").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /[A-Za-z ]/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    alert ("this is not in English");//put any message here!!!
});
```

After your comments:

Every key on the keyboard has a keycode. So when you press a key like E, the computer will interpret it as a keycode (69, in this case). It's difficult to make the computer understand the difference between French E or English E.

If you dont want to alert the user, just replace the alert with `return false;`.

*If you need to detect the browser language*:

Use this:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
alert ("The language you are using is: " + userLang);
if(userLang!=whatever-you-want){
    alert("only whatever-you-want allowed!!!")
}
```

[Check your language](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/saZ2g/)

Comment: @VAGABOND- You restricted only the non alphabetic key..right?
My problem is Please change your keyboard language from your control panel and type in to that text box.. Its not restricting

Comment: eventually you wanna allow only english and if its not in english..you wanna change that language by javascript..or instead just alert the user that I will accept only english..

Comment: Yes, that I want But the alert message is not taken.. The problem is the letter 'E' is same for English and French. So It can't understand which language is this. Clearly the same ASCII is used in the both languages.

Comment: wohoo..There is no way to tell your computer the difference between french E and English E...so just alert user that only english is accepted...

Comment: every alphabet on the keyboard have some keycode.So when you press some alphabet,like E...the computer will interpret as a keycode ..So its difficult to make the computer understand that its frenh E or English E..

Comment: Ok...Understood.. where we put the alert message?

Comment: @VASABOND-Sorry. I was not here.. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Regex` and allow only `a-zA-z`  without any accents or funny letters.